# Passing Env. into my application-config.xml

Tags: java, spring, config

I'm currently working on a java application. The application has 3 different properties files. I want to be able to set the name of the properties file based on the name of the server the app is running on.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
     <list>
        <value>classpath:/config/InfSit.properties</value>      
     </list>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

This is from my application-config.xml and currently works fine. I want to be able to change the name of the properties file based on the server the application is running on. So "InfSit.properties" would be "Inf${Env}.properties" (or something along these lines) - But I need a way to pass in the ${Env} parameter (could even be a string from another class). Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set system property in java args

```
java -Denv=Sit ...
```

and it will replace ${env} in location expr

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config/Inf${env}.properties" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variable and reference it, I do similar with CATALINA_HOME :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/database_UAT.properties"
                                  ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Just make sure you set the variable correctly ...